# Show that $B \in \Bbb M_3 (\Bbb Z).$

Tags: matrix-analysis

Let $A \in \Bbb M_3 (\Bbb Z)$ be such that $A=B^2,$ for some $B \in \Bbb M_3 (\Bbb R).$ Show that $B \in \Bbb M_3 (\Bbb Z).$

Comment: There have [been](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117594/can-we-say-that-x-in-bbb-m-3-bbb-z) several [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117547/similarity-of-matrices-and-its-square-root-over-mathbb-z) recently on the [interaction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117002/square-root-of-a-matrix-a-and-matrices-similar-to-a) between $3\times 3$ matrices over $\Bbb Z$ and over $\Bbb R$. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case when
$$ B = \left(
\begin{matrix}
\sqrt 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt 2
\end{matrix}
\right).$$
Then $B^2 = 2I$. It appears your claim is false.

Comment: Yeah you are right.